# How to associate visibility of Settings menu item with visibility of Developer menu in AOSP?

Tags: menuitem, android-source

I need to associate visibility of menu Item (for example print item) with visibility of Developer menu in android. How to properly do it?  I just started to work with AOSP on Nexus 7.

Answer (score 0):

The developer menu item is enabled based on the below code , you could check the same conditions to enable other menu items  :

http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/deviceinfo/BuildNumberPreferenceController.java#115